# Плавная остановка CSS-анимации при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хотелось бы сделать анимацию, плавно останавливающуюся при наведении курсора.
 Свойство `animation-play-state: paused`, к сожалению, останавливает её резко. Какой наилучший способ решения данной задачи средствами CSS и JS?

UPD:Сам я написал такого вида скрипт. при наведении он несколько раз ставит анимацию на паузу и запускает её снова. Вышло, откровенно говоря, убого, потому как замедление происходит рывками, да ещё и утечка памяти где-то затерялась.

```
  function smoothPause(id) {
  var stopTime, runTime, ms, timer,
      isOver = false,
      isRunning = true,
      frameTime = 25, // ms
      list = document.getElementById(id),
      items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

  list.onmouseenter = onMouseEnter;
  list.onmouseleave = onMouseLeave;

  function onMouseLeave() {
    runTime = 4;
    isOver = false;
    smooth(isOver);    
  }

  function onMouseEnter() {
    stopTime = 4;
    isOver = true;
    smooth(isOver);
  }

  function smooth(isOver) {
    if (isOver) {
      runTime = Math.max(frameTime - stopTime, 4);
      ms = isRunning ? stopTime : runTime;

      timer = setTimeout(function() {

        toggleRun();

        if (ms < frameTime) {
          stopTime += 2;
          smooth(isOver);
        } else {
          stop(items);
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
      } , ms);
    } else {
      stopTime = Math.max(frameTime - runTime, 4);
      ms = isRunning ? stopTime : runTime;

      timer = setTimeout(function() {


        toggleRun();

        if (ms < frameTime) {
          runTime += 2;
          smooth(isOver);
        } else {
          run(items);
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
      } , ms);
    }
  }

  function toggleRun() {
    if(isRunning) {
      stop(items);
      isRunning = false;
    } else {
      run(items);
      isRunning = true;
    }
  }

  function stop(lis) {
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
      lis[i].style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
    }
  }
  function run(lis) {
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
      lis[i].style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    }
  }
}

smoothPause('why-images');
```

Comment: больше кода можно, вариантов много. Можешь скинуть пример как сделал?

Comment: обновил выше :]